# Binding from Element within UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, there's a UserControl with a `TextBlock`

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl">
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="text"/>
</UserControl>
```

And then, I want to bind the TextBlock's `Text` property to a Window's `TextBox`

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow">
    <local:MyControl x:Name="myControl"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ...}"/>
</Window>
```

How can I do this?
I tried `{Binding myControl.Text, ElementName=myControl}`, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserControl needs to expose a property so that you can use an ElementBinding to bind it in the Window. 
The best way would probably be to create a dependency property "Text" of type string in your UserControl's code behind file und bind to it:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Name="Root">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Root}" />
</UserControl>
```

And then in your Window bind it like this:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <test:MyControl Text="Hello" x:Name="myControl" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=myControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

*Another way:*
If you do not want the overhead of creating a dependency Property in your control you could use a non used existing property like the Tag property:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <UserControl Tag="Hello" x:Name="MyControl">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TB" Text="{Binding Tag, ElementName=MyControl}" />
        </UserControl>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=Tag, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Alternatively to `ElementName=Root` you may also set `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}`.